# How to set offset on (selectmenu) overlays in jQuery Mobile [using a fixed header toolbar]?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, offset, select-menu

**Is there a way to define the offset JQM uses for selectmenu overlay?**

Other options can be set via prototyping like this:

```js
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn   = true;
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnTheme = "a";
```

### Problem description

jQuery Mobile determines the size of the screen and decides how to display the overlay for select menus. Unfortunately this seems to work only without using a **fixed** header toolbar, because JQM is generation the source over here always with the top-offset of 30px `style="left: 741.65px; top: 30px;`.

There is no ways to overwrite this with CSS only, because the specificity of the css rules are always lower than the ones of an style-attribute!

I don't want to change the JQM sourcecode, because I'd have to change it again with every release. And I don't use the uncompressed sources.

#### Generated source from JQM

```html
<div class="ui-selectmenu ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all ui-body-a pop in"
     style="left: 741.65px; top: 30px;">
```

### Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/V8AAB/

### JQM Source code

This is the corresponding code from jQuery Mobile 1.0RC2:

```js
self.menuType = "overlay";

self.screen.height( $(document).height() ).removeClass( "ui-screen-hidden" );

// Try and center the overlay over the button
var roomtop = btnOffset - scrollTop,
    roombot = scrollTop + screenHeight - btnOffset,
    halfheight = menuHeight / 2,
    maxwidth = parseFloat( self.list.parent().css( "max-width" ) ),
    newtop, newleft;

if ( roomtop > menuHeight / 2 && roombot > menuHeight / 2 ) {
    newtop = btnOffset + ( self.button.outerHeight() / 2 ) - halfheight;
} else {
    // 30px tolerance off the edges
    newtop = roomtop > roombot ? scrollTop + screenHeight - menuHeight - 30 : scrollTop + 30;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this would help but could you scale it in the meta tag? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: I already use this meta tag in the head. The problem is jquery mobile dertemining the padding/offset based upon the screenheight and not considering the height of the fixed toolbar.

Comment: I added an JSfiddle sample of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/V8AAB/

Comment: Thanks @smamatti this looks like a jQM bug, submitted issue here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2799

Comment: @PhillPafford Thanks! I can work with the workaround posted by **agcolom** until this is fixed. :) `.ui-selectmenu { z-index: 1100 !important; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested Fix:

```
.ui-selectmenu { z-index: 1100 !important; }
```

Comment: I can work with the workaround posted by agcolom until this is fixed. :) Thanks for submitting the issue at github!

Comment: Looks like this fixed this and should be in the next release: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commit/3f488e1cd6979e27993584adfd74b4c41c9bf8f8